# Check a string for consonants

Tags: java, contains, indexof

I want to write a method to check a `string` for *consonants* using either `.contains` or `.indexOf`.

I guess I could do it the long way and check for every *consonant* in the alphabet but I know there is a better way. This is what I have so far but like I said this is sort of the long way, I think.

```
   public boolean containsConsonant(String searchString) {
        if(searchString.contains("b") || searchString.contains("c")){
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you explicitly ask using `contains` or `indexOf`

in case - if you can use `matches` - it would be very easy to implement.

```
public boolean containsConsonant(String searchString){
    String consonants = ".*[bcdfghj].*";  //list the characters to be checked
    return searchString.matches(consonants);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think matches should work just fine. But could you tell me what the '.+' is for?

Comment: I am just using regular expression here to void loops and conditions. '.' means any char. * -> 0 or more occurance

Comment: basically these consonants - can be anywhere in the string. as long as they are present in the string, it will return true

Comment: @vins - this works great! But is there no method for checking for consonants? `string.substring(0,1).hasConsonant`?

Comment: @vins - I would ask this in a question, but it would be a duplicate so....

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple `for` loop is most readable here, you can test that a character is within the desired range with a boolean and. And you can use an or test to skip vowels. Something like,

```
public boolean containsConsonant(String searchString) {
    if (searchString == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for (char ch : searchString.toCharArray()) {
        char lower = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        if (lower >= 'a' && lower <= 'z') {
            if (lower == 'a' || lower == 'e' || lower == 'i' || 
                    lower == 'o' || lower == 'u') continue;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Optimization

You could then *optimize* the above (and *directly* to your question) by using `contains` on an extracted constant `String` of `vowels`. Something like,

```
private static final String vowels = "aeiou";
public static boolean containsConsonant(final String searchString) {
    if (searchString == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for (char ch : searchString.toCharArray()) {
        char lower = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        if (lower >= 'a' && lower <= 'z' && !vowels.contains(String.valueOf(lower))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: that includes all letters, not consonants only

Comment: @Maljam Oops. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

you can create say an array containing all consonants and then run it using a loop
e.g.

```
String[] consonants{"b", "c",....}
boolean containsConsonants(String searchString, String[]arr){
for (String consonant: arr){
    if(searchString.contains(str)){ return true} return False
```